# Left Outer Join (or) Union which is more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am working on a search functionality where in the database is designed as shown.
[image]

I have to return the top 20 rows where

- TableA.[Column 3] **OR** TableC.[Column B] **OR** TableB.[Column X] 
  **CONTAINS** the @SearchText.

This is a massive database that has several million records in each one of its tables. A full-text catalog has been created on this database with several full-text indexes.

The Search Query is as follows ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.ID,
  A.Column1,
  A.Column2,
  A.Column3,
  L.Description
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L ON A.Code = L.Code
WHERE CONTAINS(A.Column3, @SearchText)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.ID,
  A.Column1,
  A.Column2,
  A.Column3,
  L.Description
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L ON A.Code = L.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.Id = B.FK_ID
WHERE CONTAINS(B.ColumnX, @SearchText)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.ID,
  A.Column1,
  A.Column2,
  A.Column3,
  L.Description
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L ON A.Code = L.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C ON A.Id = C.FK_ID
WHERE CONTAINS(C.ColumnB, @SearchText)
```

**Questions**

1) Will this Query perform better - it is very concise.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.ID,
  A.Column1,
  A.Column2,
  A.Column3,
  L.Description
FROM TableA A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L ON A.Code = L.Code
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.Id = B.FK_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C ON A.Id = C.FK_ID
WHERE CONTAINS((A.Column3, B.ColumnX, C.ColumnB), @SearchText)
```

2) Will creating a view MyView with the lookup table left outer joined with TableA improve performance as in ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  V.ID,
  V.Column1,
  V.Column2,
  V.Column3,
  V.Description
FROM MyView V
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON V.Id = B.FK_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C ON V.Id = C.FK_ID
WHERE CONTAINS((V.Column3, B.ColumnX, C.ColumnB), @SearchText)
```

Comment: have you checked execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid you cannot avoid full-text search without building complex custom-made indexing mechanizm... But you can reduce number of joined rows in the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.ID,
  A.Column1,
  A.Column2,
  A.Column3,
  L.Description
FROM TableA A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L ON A.Code = L.Code
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT FK_ID FROM TableB WHERE CONTAINS(ColumnX,@SearchText))B ON A.Id = B.FK_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT FK_ID FROM TableC WHERE CONTAINS(ColumnB,@SearchText))C ON A.Id = C.FK_ID
WHERE 
  CONTAINS(A.Column3, @SearchText)
  OR B.FK_ID IS NOT NULL
  OR C.FK_ID IS NOT NULL
```